# Animación de carga c# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

Tengo un botón que ejecuta un método de esta forma:

```
private async void BtnGraficar_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   if (rangoTiempo.Length != 0)
     {
        Draw();
     }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Por favor seleccione un rango de tiempo.");
        }
    }
```

El método draw es algo demorado en su ejecución y me congela la pantalla mas o menos de 3 a 4 minutos y al final me abre otra ventana con la grafica, pero necesito que mientras eso pase poder mostrar una animación de carga,no estoy muy familiarizado con el tema async/await alguien podria decirme como puedo detectar cuando inicia el metodo Draw() para poder inicializar una animación mediante un metodo por ejemplo: Animar(true) y al terminar la ejecución de Draw() volver a llamar a ese mismo metodo para parar la animación de la forma Animar(False)? Lo he intentado pero se sigue bloqueando la interfaz al no saber de que forma puedo jugar con la asincronia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si tu metodo no Draw es async utiliza esta forma

```
    private async void BtnGraficar_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (rangoTiempo.Length != 0)
        {
            this.Loading = true;
            try
            {
//No async
                await Task.FromResult(Draw());

//Async
                await Draw();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                 MessageBox.Show(ex.StackTrace);
            }
            finally
            {
                this.Loading = false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Por favor seleccione un rango de tiempo.");
        }
    }
```

NOTA: Puedes Utilizar El Loading como una propiedad de tipo bool y donde puedes mostrar un control loadin de tu preferencia. o una ventana.

Aquí tienes unos ejemplos: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6359848/wpf-loading-spinner

Comment: Mi método no es async por defecto, aunque podría intentar hacerlo de esta forma, actualmente es de la forma: private void draw (); no retorna nada y dentro de él llama a otros métodos, puedo usar el fromResult (Draw()) aún cuando draw() no retorna nada?

Comment: Correcto, aunque no retorno algún valor puedes esperar  a que termine y continuar con el proceso siguiente. en este caso detener el loading

Answer (score 0):

El truco es que tienes que *esperar* (`await`) a que termine la tarea.

Inténtalo con algo así:

```
private async void BtnGraficar_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (rangoTiempo.Length != 0)
    {
        // Inserta aquí la animación
        await Taks.Run(() => Draw());
        // Detén la animación
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Por favor seleccione un rango de tiempo.");
    }
}
```

Al estar en WPF, puedes crear un `.xaml` con la animación que desees. Solo necesitas [utilizar Blend](https://www.google.com.mx/search?q=tutorial+wpf+animaciones+blend&oq=tutorial+wpf+animaciones+blend) y un poco de imaginación. En un programa reciente que hice, coloqué una animación que está todo el tiempo ahí, pero con `Visibility="Hidden"` y a la hora de ejecutar la otra tarea, simplemente tenía que cambiarla por `"Visible"`:

```
<!-- XAML -->
<Frame Source="/Resources/Images/LoadingAnimation.xaml" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" x:Name="reading"/>


// C#
reading.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
```